# How to switch current user using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, switch-user

my task is to create new windows local user, log in, using it and then do some actions. Creating new user wasn't a problem but i don't know how to switch current user to new one.

What i did is a piece of script which start new powershell window using new user:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($config_name, $secpasswd)
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $mycreds -NoNewWindow
```

Is is possible to start doing rest of the script in this new window??

Comment: $config_name is actually the username

Answer (score 5):

Simple way is following:

1. Create a script (let's call it init.ps1)
2. Put in it all actions you want to invoke for user
3. Add execute right to this script to $config_name
4. Change your last line to (-noexit is just for debugging, without it powershell will close window after execution finish):

> Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $mycreds -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-noexit -command FULL_PATH_TO_SCRIPT\init.ps1"
>   
>   More difficult way is to install WinRM and use commands with Enter-PSSession (examples in the end of this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx)

Comment: "3. Add execute right to this script to $config_name" ::: where is this done? I don't see $config_name mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Why didn't you flesh out init.ps1 ? Isn't that what we need to know to switch user? Also why wouldn't you point out how to pass creds?